# Using Smart Booleans with Subsurface modifier to get smooth edges

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

I have a mesh which has the subsurface modifier applied to it. And I have made an indentation of a hole within the mesh, and the edges are catching the reflections. I also did a smart Boolean operation, but the edges are too sharp and look fake. I rearranged the modifier stack and put the Bevel above the Boolean operation, but its making it look incorrect. is there a way I can use the Smart Booleans to get reflections on the edges? I also tried the decimate modifier in case it cleans it up, also the weighted normal modifier in case it could help, but it only became worse.

[image]

Comment: I think you will find this tutorial very useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZXYWzv02m4 Any chance of sending us this file? I would like to test my hard surface modeling knowledge on it. I learned few tricks recently.

Comment: Its a good tutorial and has good information about topology, but imagine having to make 5 holes here, 10 over there, etc etc, and having to clean up your vertices each time, so I'm looking for a better method if there is one.

Comment: check this out, i think it's way easier https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EeGXh59m1s4

Comment: Hi Chris, that's how I got the hole in my example which is shown beneath the Smart Boolean operation, hence it gets smoothed edges.  Thanks for the video recommendation though.

Comment: so your problem is just, that the edges are too sharp?

Comment: Yes, I intend to use the Smart Booleans often, but the edges are too sharp. I saw I can use a node called Bevel, which smoothens the edges using cycles render, but I'd like to know a method using modelling and not done with nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Usually hard surface modeling workflow avoids to make holes in a sphere exactly due to those problems. Also you should never add subdivision before a bevel. Bevel only works well when the vertices of the sphere are not caught inside the bevel.

[image: Rerfect]

When they get to close you see artifacts.

[image: Artifacts]

The denser the topology the harder it is to keep vertices away.

[image: Many artefacts]

That's why I suggest not to use subdivision surface.

As a pro tip you can also keep bevel segments low when you use weighted normals modifier after the bevel.

This is single segment bevel without weighted normals.

[image: Perfect]

The setup I usually use:

[image: Modifiers]

And this is after weighted normals modifier was added.

[image: Normals]

Looks just like a bevel with many segments, but it has much smaller chance of generating artifacts.

Only other solution is to apply the modifiers and perform manual cleanup. Several commercial add-ons (I think it was BoxCutter or HardOps) ships with a script to clear the topology to fix exactly this problem.